# Dynamically configuring retention.ms not working for a kafka topic

Tags: apache-kafka

I have a Kafka topic called `retention` and Below are the server configuration related to retention:

```
log.retention.hours=168
log.segment.bytes=1073741824
log.retention.check.interval.ms=3600000 (~ 1 hour)
log.cleaner.enable=true
```

And below is the topic specific config:

```
retention.ms=2592000000,retention.bytes=3298534883328
```

where retention.ms ~ 30d and retention.bytes = ~ 3.29 TB

I configured the `retention.ms` and `retention.bytes` using the below command recently (on 14th Jan 2019) using below commands:

```
./bin/kafka-topics.sh --zookeeper localhost:2181 --alter --topic retentions --config retention.bytes=219902325555
```

Here the configuration for the `retntion.bytes` seems to be working while `retention.ms` does not seem to be working. Here is the evidence that I could collect:

```
cd log_dir/retentions-0/
ls -lrt 00000000000000000000.*
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 294387381 Nov 26 22:37 00000000000000000000.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root      3912 Jan 14 18:06 00000000000000000000.index
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root      5868 Jan 14 18:06 00000000000000000000.timeindex
```

If we look into the logs of older segments these are nearly 2 months old.

Can anybody tell which of these two configurations will take effect on priority Or, both can work whichever crosses the configured threshold.

In my assumptions, both configurations should work in conjunction. Plz, let me know if this is not the case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both work in conjunction.

From *Kafka: The Definitive Guide* book

> If you have specified a value for both `log.retention.bytes` and `log.retention.ms` ... messages may be removed when either criteria is met.